# Unexpected if vhdl

Tags: vhdl

This error has been mindfucking me for long, I don't know what to do. I get the same error in other codes, but this one is a simple one, so maybe it's easier to find out what's the problem.

It's a frequency selector, if the switch (clau) is on, the frequency changes.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.numeric_bit.ALL; 

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity selector_frequencia is
Port ( unHz : in bit ;
       centHz : in bit ;
       Clock : out bit;
          clau: in bit);
end selector_frequencia;

architecture Behavioral of selector_frequencia is

begin
if (clau = "0") then Clock <= unHz;
else Clock <= centHz;
end if;

end Behavioral;
```

And the error I get is this one:

ERROR:HDLParsers:164 - "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrador/Escritorio/practica_digital/practica_digital/selector_frequencia.vhdl" Line 23. parse error, unexpected IF

Thank you.

Comment: BTW, even if you get this working, this design will result in random-length runt clock pulses if your select signal `clau` is ever changed while the circuit is in operation. This flaw makes any synchronous logic using the resultant clock completely unreliable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really an expert in VHDL but I believe you should use the `if` statement inside a process:

```
architecture Behavioral of selector_frequencia is

begin

fqsel:PROCESS(unHz , centHz , Clock , clau)
BEGIN

  if (clau = '0') then
      Clock <= unHz;
  else
      Clock <= centHz;
  end if;

END PROCESS fqsel;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Your problem here is `clau = "0"`, which must be `clau = '0'` since clau is a bit, not a bit_vector.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really pay attention to the types. A bit weird that it would give "unexpected if" in that case, though?

Answer (score 1):

As Alex pointed out, your if statement needs to be inside a process block.  In addition, VHDL is not C...you are not supposed to put parens () around the conditional or it looks like a procedure/function call or a signal range ie: my_bus(7 downto 0) but it's a syntax error because if is a reserved word.  Try:

```
process (clau, unHz, centHz)
begin
  if clau = '0' then 
    Clock <= unHz;
  else 
    Clock <= centHz;
  end if;
end process;
```

Finally, outside of a process, you can just use a conditional signal assignment, which is a short-hand way of implementing the equivalent process and if statements:

```
Clock <= unHz when clau='0' else centHz;
```

Comment: An `if` with parenthesis is NOT a syntax error. `if (clau = '0') then` would be perfectly acceptable (but bad style) here.

Comment: You're right, of course...you can use parens to force operator order for the if conditionals.  I tend to write code where I don't have to do that, so I forget it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an assignment statement in your IF clause:

```
// This is assignment, you are assigning 'clau' to 0 and then checking it in 'if'
if (clau = "0") then Clock <= unHz;

// Try this, note the double '='
if (clau == "0") then Clock <= unHz;
```

Assignment statements should be within a PROCESS block.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work. Anyway, I'm pretty sure '=' is for comparison while '<=' is for assignation.

Comment: Is it possible you have some line-endings issue? Just a guess.

Comment: This guy has the same problem: http://www.edaboard.com/thread79581.html (read the comment by Elephantus)

Comment: There is no `==` anywhere in VHDL. Your main problem here is that `clau` is a bit, not a bit_vector, so must be compared with `'0'` not `"0"`